# Как реализовать автозаполнение с помощью Python и Flask

Tags: html, python, веб-программирование, flask

Есть веб приложение, которое по нажатию на кнопку  должно заполнять расположенную рядом форму данными, которые берутся из скрипта в питон.
Возможно ли реализовать это действие без перезагрузки страницы силами питона и фласк? 
Возможно ли также непрерывно получать ответ от функции питон, которая находится в цикле и выводить результат на сайт?

Comment: На одном лишь питоне не получится. Вам нужен будет Javascript. Для выполнения запросов к бэкенду без перезагрузки страницы вам нужен AJAX. Вы можете написать функцию на Javascript, через определенный промежуток времени будет делать запрос и обновлять часть страницы.

Comment: Как уже написали выше, немного джаваскрипта в любом случае понадобится. А вот по поводу AJAX - возможны варианты. Если задача - держать постоянную связь между веб-интерфейсом и питоновским бэкендом, то, возможно, стоит использовать не AJAX, а веб-сокеты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В js есть очень удобная и очень маленькая библиотечка `axios`. Используя её на клиенте можно написать простой обработчик событий, в котором написать что-то такое

```
axios.post("/server/api/", {data: "Any javasript object"}).then(
  (response) => {
    // Можно обновить что угодно.
  }
);
```

Для полноценного использования [readme](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md) более, чем достаточно.

На стороне сервера достаточно написать

```
from flask import jsonify

#....

@app.route("/server/api/", methods=["POST"])
def api():
    # Тут можно делать что угодно
    return jsonify(response=data_object)
```

Главное -- следить за слешами в урлах и следить за тем, чтобы данные, которыми обмениваются клиент и сервер, были согласованными.

Чтобы делать автодополнение примерно так же, как это делает гугл, то это надо на каждую введённую букву отправлять ajax-запрос на сервер.

Если хочется автообновления страницы, как в чате, то тут нужны websockets. У Мигеля Гринберга есть великолепный [обучающий материал](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) на эту тему. У него же есть [готовый пример](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat) чата, написанный на Flask + Websockets.

Comment: Благодарю за столь развернутый ответ! В моем случае создается приложение которое автозаполняет поле с временем и номером клиента из необходимого источника. Особенность в том, что скрипт в питон проверяет наличие новых данных в базе номеров каждые 5 секунд и сохраняет их в переменную при наличии изменений. Затем, когда остальные поля заполняет оператор и нажимает кнопку отправить обновить, то данные из базы python должны попасть в содержимое html, а затем, все данные отправляются в базу SQL после нажатия другой кнопки. Я правильно понял, что мне больше подойдет axios для реализации этого?

Comment: Да, проще сделать через обычные ajax-запросы, без сокетов.